# Upgrade the react-script from 4 to 5 cause errors on polyfills

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-scripts

I upgraded my **React** from 17 to 18 and upgrade the **react-script** from 4 to 5, when I want to run the app below errors occur:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error saying that  webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js . it seems you are using webpack 5 so  is no longer the case .  to solve this error :

**1-** install **node-polyfill-webpack-plugin**  :  `npm install node-polyfill-webpack-plugin`

**2-** go to **webpack.config.js**  and add this :
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")

```
module.exports = {
    // Other rules...
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ]
}
```

Comment: when we create a new app with CRA, the react-script version is 5 but doesn't create webpack config file, why now we need it?

Comment: when using create-react-app. Webpack is set up under the hood . to check it's version got to **package.json** inside **react-script**

Comment: this is the [link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/package.json)  in the github repo . you'll find that the version of react-script is `"version": "5.0.1",` and for webpack it's in the **"dependencies"** is `"webpack": "^5.64.4",`

Comment: Now it upgrade a project that using create-react-app, my question is that when it was using react-script 4 there isn't any webpack config file but now that I want to upgrade to 5 I should add it, why? Because now it is using create-react- app too

Comment: No. You were using **webpack v4** with **react-script 4**

Comment: You don't install it   manually it comes with  cra automatically